# TCPDF - How to make the printing faster? It is very very slow, 1320 records took 40 minutes

Tags: php, windows, zend-framework, zend-db, tcpdf

Using Zend framework and TCPDF this is taking 40 minutes to print the Test.pdf. I having now no idea how to reduce this abnormal time to something normal?

```
set_time_limit(0);
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 8, '', true);
$pdf->AddPage();
/* Database mysql gives the records and it is wrapped with <table> */
$html = "<table>1310 records.... with some simple <tr><td></td></tr></table>";
$pdf->writeHTMLCell($w=0, $h=0, $x='', $y='', $html, $border=0, $ln=1, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);
$pdf->Output('Test.pdf', 'I');
exit;
```

**Follow up:** (tune the performance)

1) php.ini:
memory_limit = 512M
max_execution_time = 0

2) Codeing
 $pdf->setFontSubsetting(false); // true to false

3) Debug shows, following taking the whole time

$pdf->writeHTMLCell($w=0, $h=0, $x='', $y='', $html, $border=0, $ln=1, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);

Comment: Are you doing one SQL query or 1320 queries in SQL?

Comment: You should metric which part of your application takes how long, e.g. by profiling your code. Otherwise it's all guessing.

Comment: see my follow up. But still same.

Comment: Why are you assigning values to variables on that method call? (Method call that is taking a long time)

Comment: In my experience I've found MPDF (http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/) much faster compared to TCPDF. Beware that TCPDF is LGPL whereas MPDF is GPL.

Comment: @PeterBrooks: That's one sweet find!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since no other answers have been forthcoming, I would highly recommend a good look at [MPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/) (GPL) as it's much faster than TCPDF. I've had operations on one server that took approx three minutes using TCPDF being reduced to seconds with MPDF. I would only assume that some format of my HTML -> PDF was hitting some inefficient function in TCPDF.

Anyway I present the following code which helped me convert HTML -> PDF.

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('c');
$mpdf->setDisplayMode('fullpage');
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('css/core.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$html = "<table>1310 records.... with some simple <tr><td></td></tr></table>";
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html); 
$mpdf->Output(standardize(ampersand('filename', false)) . '.pdf', 'D');
```

This code provides a PDF outputted as a downloadable file, the MPDF documentation gives lots of other examples to suit your needs.

Comment: I could not reduce the time with TCPDF, it is a hell even not using WriteHTML simple Cell. MPDF made this fastest.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on switching from TCPDF to MPDF. Doing so reduced the PDF creation time on a certain doc from 240 seconds to 7 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

We use `mpdf` mainly because I can just "include" it with no installation.
There was some minor tweak that needed to be added to php.ini, mbstring I think.

I was able to get 75 pages a minute up to 100 pages per minute by shrinking the HTML I was feeding the `WriteHTML` verb. We do not have any graphics.

Then I use `ghostscript` to sort and cat pdfs (15 or so pages) per person receiving them. That cat process takes about 3 minutes per 800-1000-pages for the 50 or 60 people receiving a report at one destination.

All this on a box mostly sitting there for nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

One of the causes of the TCPDF slow performance could be images inserted from external URLs. DNS resolution and file downloading take time and slow down the PDF generation process.